# Database Design Approach to include new Table in existing Relationship

Tags: database, database-design, star-schema

I'm using star **schema approach** in my application.

[image]
This approach is working fine if I have defined set of Tables (**Dimensions**). Here, in this example I have defined set of tables like

```
Customer Dimension
Product Dimension
Time Dimension
Staff Dimension
```

And Base Fact Table holds the each **ForeignKey** of different Dimensions.

If I want to add new **Dimension** to existing design, I've to alter the **Base Fact** Table to include new **Foreign Key** of a new Dimension to be added.

Is there any design way or design approach available to introduce a new Dimension without altering the Base Fact? where as the Base Fact will be more generic in nature.

Comment: what's wrong with "alter the Base Fact Table to include new Foreign Key of a new Dimension to be added." - that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Every new table requires altering Base Fact. Not a good approach for larger projects with big data.

Comment: It's a perfectly fine design. I've used a similar process several times. Define big data? Anyway, you would normally know the majority (if not all) Dimensions up front.

Comment: Agree. But, are there any approaches available for such requirement.